# Qooxdoo - how do i create a new theme and use it in the application?

Tags: themes, qooxdoo

I am quite new to qooxdoo and I need help in creating a custom theme for my application.

I copied the native `Modern` theme and modified some of its features, now my question is how do I add it as new theme to qooxdoo and how can I use it in my application?

any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to copy it over, simply extending the theme would be good. If you created your app with the qooxdoo desktop skeleton using the create-application.py helper, you should already have a custom theme in place running and extending the modern theme. If not, you simply have to edit the config.json file which should be in your root project folder and search for a key named QXTHEME. The value of that key is a classname which specifies your theme. Change that to your custom theme class and rebuild the app to see the result.
Here are some further resources on how to work with themes: http://manual.qooxdoo.org/current/pages/desktop/ui_custom_themes.html

Comment: thanks for your answer but i found it more convenient to copy the files and modify them, please see my answer and let me know if it will cause any conflicts with the api.

Answer (score 0):

To add a bit to Martin's answer: You don't copy and modify theme code, you **extend** and **override**, much as with class code.

If you create an application skeleton with *create-application.py*, the default code structure under *source/class* already contains custom theme classes (under *source/class//theme/**). The thing is those theme classes extend from the *Modern* theme *without* actually overriding anything, so you effectively get the *Modern* look and feel.

But you can then go ahead and flesh out those custom theme classes, with properties that suite your taste, thereby creating your own theme.

Comment: thanks for your answer but i found it more convenient to copy the files and modify them, please see my answer and let me know if it will cause any conflicts with the api.

Answer (score -1):

i found it very difficult to create a custom theme by extending one of the existing native themes (classic, modern... etc) without looking at the source code, also i don't want to mess up the original API's files by modifying them, so i did the following:

1- replaced files in my application's directory:  `myapplication/source/class/myapplication/theme/` with the files in `/qooxdoo-directory/framework/source/class/qx/theme/modern/`. replaced four files in total (Appearance.js, Decoration.js, Color.js and Font.js).

2- copied decoration directory from `/qooxdoo-directory/framework/source/resource/qx/decoration/Modern` to my application's directory: `myapplication/source/recourse/myapplication/decoration`.

3- copied icons directory from `qooxdoo-directory/framework/source/resource/qx/icon/Tango` to my application's directory `myapplication/source/resource/myapplication/icon`.

4- copied `Tango.js` from `qooxdoo-directory/framework/source/class/qx/theme/icon/Tango.js` to my application's directory `myapplication/source/class/myapplication/theme/icon/Icon.js`.

5- edited the meta file **Themes.js** and changed it to:

```
    qx.Theme.define("myapplication.theme.Theme",
    {
      meta :
      {
        color : myapplication.theme.Color,
        decoration : myapplication.theme.Decoration,
        font : myapplication.theme.Font,
        icon : myapplication.theme.icon.Icon,
        appearance : myapplication.theme.Appearance
      }
    });
```

6- edited **Icon.js** file (which i copied from Tango.js in step 4) and changed it to:

```
    qx.Theme.define("myapplication.theme.icon.Icon",
    {
      title : "myIcons",
      aliases : {
        "icon" : "myapplication/icon"
      }
    });
```

7- edited **Decoration.js**, **Appearance.js**, **Color.js** and **Font.js** in my application's theme directory and changed the classes' namespaces from:

```
qx.Theme.define("qx.theme.modern.<file's name>",
```

to

```
qx.Theme.define("myapplication.theme.<file's name>",
```

8- corrected assets paths in **Decoration.js** and **Appearance.js** from the original path `qx/decoration/Modern` or `qx/icon/Tango` to the one relevant to my appliaction `myapplication/decoration` and `myapplication/icon`, for example:

```
    @asset(qx/decoration/Modern/toolbar/toolbar-part.gif)
```

changed to

```
    @asset(myapplication/decoration/toolbar/toolbar-part.gif)
```

ps: the relative path in an application is `application-name/source/resource`, so you can refer to any directory in this folder by `application-name/folder-name`.

9- likewise in step 8 i changed aliases in decoration.js to:

```
    aliases : {
      decoration : "myapplication/decoration"
    },
```

10 - ran generate.py file in `myapplication/source`.

and done, now i can change anything i want without crashing the API :)

Comment: -1 Well, it's kind of sad, as every single change you are now doing to the theme files you could have done **without** copying the framework classes, just by adding to your locally derived theme. At least you could spare yourself copying image resources, as the Generator finds icons and other resources across libraries. You are just duplicating files unnecessary. Maybe you want to re-consider the much cleaner approach of deriving a theme one day.

Comment: i'm currently learning how to use the decorators and appearances and for that purpose only i copied the files so that i can see the source code and learn from it, once i have enough experience i would extend themes like you mentioned in your answer ofcorse. i also copied the images because i replaced lots of them and i wanted to keep the original ones.