# Tried to change theme in project, is not working anymore

Tags: qooxdoo

I've been working in a project since 3 months, at first was with Modern theme as default, after some changes I applied Indigo theme and kept working, yesterday tried to switch back to Modern without success, after several tries I followed step by step some directions another guy posted here : `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19820195/qooxdoo-how-do-i-create-a-new-theme-and-use-it-in-the-application` surely I did something wrong because I didn't get Modern theme on, so, I undo everything. Now if I try to generate source I get many errors about resources and directories already deleted, my guess is that something is left at cache or somewhere else. Please can you help to apply modern theme correctly or at least anything I can continue working. Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to see the modern theme in your app without alterations, edit your `config.json` to include the line

```
"QXTHEME": "qx.theme.Modern",
```

then run generate.

Comment: Tobi, thank you for your help however : generate source and build passes ok, but I get nothing on screen. generate source-all still shows earlier errors. Do I have to reinstall the sdk again ?

Comment: no certainly not, unless you have changed the sdk ... if you say you get nothing on screen, you mean 'empty screen' or still the old theme ?

Comment: Empty, background in gray color and that's it. I'm pretty sure I didn't touch sdk's files. The funny thing is if I want to start another project by copying and pasting code from the old one, it doesnt work either, looks to me there is something left in cache or something. The code was working fine, I just wanted to change theme...

Comment: If reinstalling is solution I will, I got just a few mini projects because I'm learning QX, this one is the most advanced in features I've done. All I want is keep working on it. Regards

Comment: Tobi, I got it !!! I download sdk again, I delete cache directory and after a few adjustments is working back again in Modern theme. I really appreciate your time. Thanks a lot.